# Grabbing multiple attachments with a specific file name in Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, docx-mailmerge

Needing help with adding 'n' number of attachments.

Code below:

```
    for(var i = 2; i<=lr; i++)
    {
          var Contact_Person = ss.getRange(i,4).getValue();

          var PDFs = ss.getRange(i,6).getValue();

          //The above i am grabbing the PDF name from a column in My sheet.

          //This name is used for generating my Mail Merge File.
    
          var contents = DriveApp.getFolderById('1ouiQE2cERaRMC_rnSftJCqQCpr2B4x3D').getFiles();
             
          PDFs = DriveApp.getFilesByName(Contractor_Name);
          if(PDFs.hasNext())
          {

              var attach = [];

              while(contents.hasNext())
              {

                   var file = contents.next();

                   if (file.getMimeType() == "application/pdf")
                   {

                       attach.push(file);

                   }

             }
           
  
        GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, Subject, messageBody,
        {

          attachments: [PDFs.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF), attach[0],attach[1],attach[2], attach[3],],

          name: 'Test'

        });
     }

//This section is for me to grab 1 attachment according to the name specified for that row matching

//the Merged file in the google drive folder.

//I am also trying to attach from a separate folder N number of files to this email.
```

Pdfs is a variable holding getting values from Column 6 in my Spreadsheet.

This column per row has a set of names.

When the program runs it performs a mail merge and then sends an email to the user of a specific row.

Example:

```
Email           Subject  Reference No.  Contact Person  Contractor Name   PDFs
***@gmail.com    Test    XXXXX          Mr. Dan         XYZ Company       XYZ Company
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can just push them all to the same array.*

#### More Information:

From the documentation on `GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`:

> **Advanced parameters**
>
> `attachments` `BlobSource[]` an array of files to send with the email

So you can attach them all in one array.

#### Code Snippet:

```js
if (PDFs.hasNext()) {
  var attach = [];
  attach.push(PDFs.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF));

  while (contents.hasNext()) {
    var file = contents.next();
    if (file.getMimeType() == "application/pdf") {
      attach.push(file);
    }
  }

  GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, Subject, messageBody, {
    attachments: attach,
    name: "Test"
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [Class GmailApp - `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. 

The reason i dont want to grab everything is cos i am also using the same folder for other users.. Meaning that the PDF variable is used to identify the exact user and then grabs extra attachments from a different folder to send out an email to the individual users.

Comment: @KingMichaelKing Do you know what 'N' is in advance?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. This will attach the first file in the folder `PDFs` and all the files inside `attach` to the email. If you only want to get N files from `attach`, how do you know what N is?

Comment: Hi -  PDFs is actually a variable that stores the username on (column 6).
            var PDFs = ss.getRange(i,6).getValue();
So once the name of the user is stored inside variable PDFs, i then select the file that matches the name stored in variable PDFs.
          PDFs = DriveApp.getFilesByName(Contractor_Name);
So this N, is determined by the PDFs variable.

Perhaps i am doing it wrongly.. kindly advise if there is a better approach.

1. Folder 1 = Holds Mail Merged Files of different users with their names used to name the file.
2. Folder 2 = Holds files to be attached to all user

Comment: `PDFs = DriveApp.getFilesByName(Contractor_Name);` PDFs is a list of `File`s. Can you please update your question to clarify the variables so I can take another look?

Comment: That is not how `getFilesByName()` works. Where is `Contractor_Name`? You redefine `PDF`s without doing anything with the values you got from the Sheet so how do you expect to get the specific files pertaining to the contractor?

Comment: Yes correct it is a of files with different names.
Each name receives a file unique to them by their name but all get a set of attachment that is common to all that sets on a different folder on Gdrive.

So am trying to send a file that matches "user a" where file name is "user a"  with eg. 10 files from a different folder and "user b" where file name is "user b" but the 10 attachments also is sent to "user b".

Comment: Where do you assign `Contractor_Name`?

Comment: Thank you for your update. In column 6, is there a list of PDF names, or just one PDF?

Comment: Hi, yes there is a list of pdf names.

Comment: Hi @ Rafa Guillermo, thanks again for your assistance. I actually noticed that i wasn't specifying the drive folder where to grab the users individual files.

Works fine now.