# Fail to send email with attachment in google app scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Just need your help and advise. I am quite new in coding stuff. Recently, I have coded below stuff. I was expecting to fill in all the blanks on google form including users' email as long as the form has been submitted, it will be recorded to a google spreadsheet and generate a pdf then send to the email address that was typed in the google form. I have tested below scripts, now function afterFormSubmit and function createPDF both working the pdf file could be generated properly and all the information is populated into the google doc properly then convert to pdf formate however function sendEmail does not work. When I run function sendemail , it returns error message "Exception: Invalid argument: attachments (line 36, file "Code")" Could someone please help ?

```js
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info); 
  const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  ws.getRange(entryRow, 7).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
  ws.getRange(entryRow, 8).setValue(pdfFile.getName());
  sendEmail(e.namedValues['Student Email'][0],pdfFile);
}


function sendEmail(currentEmail,pdfFile){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").activate();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){
    
    var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
    var currentStudentName = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var currentName = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue(); 
    var messageBody = templateText.replace("{recipient}",currentName);
    var subjectLine = "Congratulations on your merit!" + currentStudentName;
    GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody, {
      attachments:[pdfFile],
      name: 'St Clare Merits'});
  }
}

function createPDF(info) {
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1WIgfR7YESk6fcRPbzKa_Gsi_yp3-gemg");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1QgnNLCbmm1z9RvPQCjA-vSnuw-P1Fw4X");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1fh5uRKQ9WZOY-ngXK0sOxH85UX_HHR1HYDefQhjfZVI");
  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{name}", info['Student name'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{reason}", info['Reason for Merit'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Sname}", info['Staff Name'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Date}", info['Date'][0]);
  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Student name'][0]+ " " + new Date());
  newTempFile.setTrashed(true);
  return pdfFile; 
}
```

Comment: Your attachments have to be an array of `[BlobSource]` objects, not `[File]`s. Try returning `blobPDF` from `createPDF`, not `pdfFile`. See [Grabbing multiple attachments with a specific file name in Google Appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165255/grabbing-multiple-attachments-with-a-specific-file-name-in-google-appscript)

Comment: Hi Rafa 

What exactly mean by an array of Blobsource? I just want to generate 1 pdf to be sent off the the email that was typed in the google form.  Could you please show me the correct code for attachments argument in my script ? thx

Comment: Check the answer I linked. You are attaching `[pdfFile]` which has a PDF type but you actually need to attach a file which is a `BlobSource` object. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options

Comment: You attachments syntax is corect but you're attaching the files in the wrong structure. Try `return blobPDF` from `createPdf` not `return pdfFile`.

Comment: in the link example, it is showing attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],  and it has to define var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');   . In my example, I do not have such file to define in var because my script will need to generate a pdf file from a google doc template with populating the data that was collected from google forms. it does not have such id. I am quite new to these coding stuff. so please show me the change in my example if you can ? thank you.

Comment: Change `return pdfFile` to `return pdfFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF)`.

Comment: //return pdfFile;
  return pdfFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
ReferenceError: PDFs is not defined
    at sendEmail

Comment: I don't understand where this is coming from.

Comment: email still could not be sent out.  showing new error ReferenceError: PDFs is not defined at sendEmail after I change code to return pdfFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF) in my original code.

Comment: But your code doesn't have any reference to `PDFs`?

Comment: Exception: Invalid argument: attachments
    at sendEmail

Now showing same error again

Comment: Okay, rather than `attachments: [pdfFile]`, instead declare a variable `var attach = [];` and push the file to is with `attach.push(pdfFile)` before GmailApp, and then send with the option `attachments: attach`.

Comment: `var attach = []; attach.push(pdfFile); GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody, {
      attachments: attach,
      name: 'St Clare Merits'});` like so

Comment: var attach = []; 
    attach.push(pdfFile);
    
    GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody, {
      name: 'St Clare Merits',
      attachments: attach,

No email with attachment sent. if click on run showing Exception: Invalid argument: attachments

Comment: of coz I saved first

Comment: Okay so I copied your code exactly, set up a test environment and ran the code. The things I assumed are: 1. `pdfFolder` and `tempFolder` both exist on your Drive. 2. `templateDoc` is a Google Docs file. I put in dummy text in the Sheet and hard coded values for `currentEmail`, `currentStudentName` etc, and the whole code worked, I received the email with no error.

Comment: do you mean my original code working  fine ?

Comment: my code was working fine a while ago but just stopped working now and returns this error saying attachments invalid.

Comment: Yes, your code exactly as it is. The only things I edited were hard-coded values to use some dummy data. What have you changed since it was working?

Comment: Nothing was changed. I post as what it is. just suddenly stopped working with such an invalid argument error coming up one day.

Comment: If i remove attachments and name from my original code in sendemail function , i still can receive the email without any attached pdf. but i need the pdf as attached in my work.

Comment: Just curious - if you copy this code into a new project and run it, do you get the same issue? You will have to replace all instances of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` to `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` to do this, though. Just trying to troubleshoot, I am wondering if this is project-specific.

Comment: Hi Rafa , after I replace SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() to SpreadsheetApp.openById(), I get the following error 
Exception: The parameters () don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.openById. (line 13, file "Code")

Comment: You need to put your Spreadheet's ID in the function call... like `SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheet-id"`...